# what happens to aws auto scaling group when we rebuild the elastic beanstalk env?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

[image]

what happens to aws auto scalling group when we rebuild the elastic beanstalk env?

It says it deletes RDS.

Does this delete auto scaling group as well?

If yes can we recover deleted ASG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the older ASG gets deleted when you rebuild env. However, it creates a new one. So the ASG name is changed.